# Contar apariciones seguidas de un valor en una tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Hola tengo una tabla que cuenta con un valor `ID` y otros valores entre los cuales se encuentra `nombre`.

```
###############
# ID # Nombre #
###############
# 4  # Juan   #
###############
# 3  # Juan   #
###############
# 2  # Juan   #
###############
# 1  # Martin #
###############
# 0  # Juan   #
###############
```

¿Es posible mediante un query MySql obtener las ocurrencias seguidas del nombre mas reciente (en este caso Juan)?

Es decir que desde el nombre mas reciente ingresado en la tabla (en este caso `Juan`) se cuente sus ocurrencias hasta que otro valor interrumpa el conteo (en este caso `Martin`).

En la tabla de ejemplo el valor retornado debería ser 3 debido a que el ultimo nombre ingresado en la tabla fue Juan y tuvo 3 ocurrencias antes de que el nombre Martin apareciera.

Comment: La idea de fondo es, dado un nombre N, saber cuánto es la máxima cantidad de veces en que ese nombre apareció seguido? O sólo importa el primer y último nombre de la tabla?

Comment: @amenadiel Hola, solo me importa el ultimo nombre que fue ingresado en la tabla, desde ahí cuantas veces seguidas se encuentra en la tabla hasta que otro nombre interrumpa la operación, es decir una vez que encuentra un nombre distinto ya no interesa el resto de la tabla

Comment: Ok, el nombre N es el último nombre. Entonces quieres saber cuánto es lo máximo que ese nombre se repite, no necesariamente desde el comienzo sino en toda la tabla

Comment: @amenadiel solo en el comienzo, como muestro en el ejemplo una vez se encuentra el nombre Martin el query termina, la tabla puede tener más repeticiones seguidas del nombre N  pero solo me interesan las repeticiones del comienzo.

Comment: otra pregunta: cómo sabes cuál es el principio y el final de la tabla, si por lo que veo tus ID no son correlativos?

Comment: @amenadiel La tabla tiene un ID auto-increment por lo que el primer dato de la tabla es 0, luego el ultimo ingresado (el mas actual) es el que tiene el mayor ID, en mi ejemplo el 4 es el ultimo elemento ingresado en la tabla y el 0 el primero. Disculpa creo que confundi un poco los términos por "el comienzo"  me refiero a la tabla vista tal cual lo mostré en el ejemplo no desde el 0, en el caso de la tabla de ejemplo desde el 4.

Comment: Ok entonces, para que la respuesta sea 3, lo que quieres es medir cuántas veces se repitió el valor más reciente de la tabla en orden descendente. Si lo haces desde el comienzo de la tabla, la respuesta sería 1

Comment: @amenadiel Claro me refiero a lo primero, desde el mas reciente, para que el resultado de 3, he actualizado la pregunta para ver si me eh expresado mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imaginemos que esta es tu tabla:

```
select * from nombres order by id;

id  nombre
0   Juan
1   Martin
2   Juan
3   Juan
4   Juan
5   Juan
6   Martin
7   Juan
8   Juan
9   Juan
```

Entonces el último nombre sale de la consulta

```
(select nombre from nombres order by id desc limit 1)
```

Puedes obtener, en una consulta, el máximo ID de la tabla junto al máximo valor distinto al último nombre:

```
select max(id) maximo_distinto, 
       (select max(id) from nombres) as ultimo_id 
from nombres 
where nombre !=(select nombre 
                from nombres 
                order by id desc 
                limit 1);
```

Y eso devuelve

```
maximo_distinto ultimo_id
6               9
```

Por lo que el resultado deseado se obtiene de la resta entre ambos.

Ahora, qué pasa cuando alguien remueve un valor intermedio?

```
id  nombre
0   Juan
1   Martin
2   Juan
3   Juan
4   Juan
5   Juan
6   Martin
8   Juan
9   Juan
```

El resultado debiera ser 2, pero con la query que te mostré, la resta de los ID seguiría diciendo 3. Hay que probar otra solución.

Por ejemplo, puedes seleccionar todos los registros en donde el ID sea superior al mayor ID distinto al último nombre (ya está sonando rebuscado)

```
select * 
from nombres 
where id >( select max(id) maximo_distinto 
            from nombres 
            where nombre !=( select nombre 
                             from nombres 
                             order by id DESC
                             limit 1));
```

Y eso devuelve

```
id  nombre
9   Juan
8   Juan
7   Juan
```

Por lo cual es cosa de hacer

```
select count(*) as juanes
from nombres 
where id >( select max(id) maximo_distinto 
            from nombres 
            where nombre !=( select nombre 
                             from nombres 
                             order by id DESC
                             limit 1));
```

Y con eso obtienes

```
juanes
3
```

Comment: Muy bueno es justo lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esta Query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tabla 
WHERE id NOT IN
(
SELECT id
FROM Tabla AS Tabla_1
WHERE nombre <> (
                  SELECT nombre FROM Tabla 
                  WHERE Tabla.id > Tabla_1.id 
                  ORDER BY id ASC 
                  LIMIT 1
                )
);
```

Para ver el ejemplo funcionando [click aquí](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1f61a/3)